# Issue with bootstrap modal's position and its dismissal on close click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am using `bootstrap v4.0.0` and `jQuery JavaScript Library v3.3.1`. I am having some issue with bootstrap modal's position and its dismissal on close click.
It is rendering perfectly (positioned incorrectly) and data is also loaded correctly. Now the two issues are as:

1. Modal get positioned to top-left corner irrespective of modal size.
2. When I click Modal's close button or X button (top right), it doesn't get dismissed. However if, i remove fade class from modal then close buttons works.

I want the modal to be positioned centrally and secondly the close modal button should work with fade class as well.

I have tested this with static code (When partial view is not used), in that case it works perfectly without any of above mentioned issues. What I have done worng? Please help.

I have tried below code:

------------------------PARENT VIEW-------------------------------

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">      
    </div>
</div>
```

-------------------------------PARTIAL VIEW-------------------------

```
@model Myproject.Models.mContact

<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">@Model.FeedbackTypeName</h3> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Feedback Type</strong> </td>
                    <td>@Model.FeedbackTypeName</td>
                    <td><strong>Sent By</strong> </td>
                    <td>@Model.FullName</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Email</strong> </td>
                    <td>@Model.Email</td>
                    <td><strong>Mobile Number</strong> </td>
                    <td>@Model.MobileNo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Sent Date</strong></td>
                    <td>@Model.CreatedDate</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Message</strong> </td>
                    <td colspan="3">@Model.Message</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default " data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>        
    </div>
</div>
```

---------------------------------JQUERY CODE ON PARENT VIEW---------------------------

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fa-eye').click(function () {
            var _id = $(this).data("id");
            var _url = '@Url.Action("FeedbackDetails","Feedback", new { Area="Contact"})';

            $.ajax({
                url: _url,
                data: { "id": _id },
                dataType: 'html',
                 contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(response) {
                    //Do Something
                    $('#myModal').html('').html(response);                    
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                },
                error: function(xhr) {
                    //Do Something to handle error
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

----------------------Controller Action----------------------------

```
public PartialViewResult FeedbackDetails(string id)
    {
        mContact obj = new mContact();
        // SOME LOGIC
        return PartialView("_FeedbackDetails", obj);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jquery ajax success function  `$("#myModal").html("")` will remove `<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">` and then you append `.html(response).` where it will bind from `<div class="modal-content">`.

So it should be :

Parent Div

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
</div>
```

Partial View

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">  
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
         <h3 class="modal-title">@Model.FeedbackTypeName</h3> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Feedback Type</strong> </td>
                <td>@Model.FeedbackTypeName</td>
                <td><strong>Sent By</strong> </td>
                <td>@Model.FullName</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Email</strong> </td>
                <td>@Model.Email</td>
                <td><strong>Mobile Number</strong> </td>
                <td>@Model.MobileNo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Sent Date</strong></td>
                <td>@Model.CreatedDate</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Message</strong> </td>
                <td colspan="3">@Model.Message</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default " data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>        
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```